# Redireccionar página con header a una carpeta de nivel inferior

Tags: php

Estoy intentando redirigir usando:

```
header("Location: archivo.php");
```

Pero resulta que ese archivo está en una carpeta de un nivel inferior. He probado con la ruta ../archivo.php pero no funciona. Se ma pasa algo ?

El archivo.php al que quiero redireccionar está en un directorio anterior.

Lo que en html suele hacerse con ../ para referirme que ese archivo está en una carpeta anterior.

Pero en la función header no me funciona

El ejemplo del código que puse me redirecciona a
    http://localhost/carpeta/archivo.php
Pero quiero que redireccione a:
    http://localhost/archivo.php es decir. a un nivel anterior de donde se encuentra el archivo que redirecciona

Comment: Saludos explica mejor la organización de tus carpetas y archivos

Comment: Edite explicando mejor

Comment: Probá si con `header("Location: ./../archivo.php");` te funciona.

Comment: Funciona! gracias. Podrías explicarme el porqué de esta solución ? Me gustaría entenderlo, ya que hasta ahora en html y en js bastaba con ../archivo para ir atrás y aquí se añade otro ./

Answer (score 2):

Deberías agregar el `./` al principio de la ruta:

```
header("Location: ./../archivo.php");
```

Lo que hace el `./` es que toma el path relativo en donde se encuentra el archivo invocado, entonces si no agregabas eso, por ahí el path te toma el directorio previo. En un ejemplo:

Path: `localhost/`
Path agregando el `./`: `localhost/carpeta/`

Entonces en éste caso deberías agregar el path relativo del archivo para que puedas aplicar el `../` para ir a una carpeta previa.